# Can't get simple INSERT to work

Tags: php, mysql, insert

For some reason I can't get a simple insert to work on my database and I'm getting no errors.

I'm hoping it is something obvious that I am missing. I can add to the table on the command line, just not from php.

Table is using the InnoDB engine. I'm fairly new to php & MySql so I'm hoping it's just a simple mistake.

```
mysqli_autocommit($con,TRUE);
echo "<BR>TIME TO ENTER THE DATA TO THE DB</BR>";

$successful = TRUE;

//Adding data to the TRIP table
$q = "INSERT INTO Trip (Date, Distance, Duration, Route, Conditions, Weather, Description, Title) 
        VALUES ('$date', '$distance', '$duration', '$route', '$conditions', '$weather', '$description', '$tripTitle')";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $q );

if($res === false){
    $successful = FALSE;
    echo "$successful = FALSE after adding data to trip table<BR>";
}
else{
    echo "<BR>Trip data entered sucessfully<BR>";
    //$tripID = mysql_insert_id();
    //echo "Trip ID = ".$tripID;
}

echo "<BR>Made it to the bottom of the code</BR>";
```

Below is the table properties.

```
CREATE TABLE `Trip` (
  `idTrip` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Distance` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Route` longtext,
  `Conditions` longtext,
  `Weather` longtext,
  `Description` longtext,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Last Edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Title` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTrip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idTrip_UNIQUE` (`idTrip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date_unique` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you're not getting errors because you're not checking for them.

Comment: You don't get any errors because you are not checking for them

Comment: @Fred-ii- Great minds think alike ;)

Comment: Echo the query and review what it showing

Comment: @JohnConde Wow, you're telling me!!!

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: $res = mysqli_query($con, $q )  or die(mysqli_error($con)); add this

Comment: Added  echo ("res = ".$res."<BR>");

it just shows up blank.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it

```
$q = "INSERT INTO Trip (Date, Distance, Duration, Route, Conditions, Weather, Description, Title) 
        VALUES ('" . $date . "', '" . $distance . "', '" . $duration . "', '" . $route . "', '" . $conditions . "', '" . $weather . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $tripTitle . "')";
```

?

Try echo $q;

and just copy the query into MySQL CLI to check if there is an error if you dont want to add mysqli_error output.

Comment: `'" . $var . "'` and `'$var'` both do the same thing.

Comment: Spot on, this helped with my query. But it's still not adding to the table.

Comment: @DavidJack are you not paying attention to comments we/I left you up there? I told you what to do.

Comment: When copying the echo'd query into the command line it worked no problem. 

But nothing from the php at the moment.

Comment: '" . $var . "' =  '$var' was new for me, too. THX! So if the Query is ok, adding the "or die(mysqli_error) would be my next step as they mentioned above.